# Can all terms of the Johnson filtration be hom-mapped onto the same nontrival group?

Tags: gr.group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

Let $F_n$ where $n \ge 3$ be a free group and let $(\mathcal A_n(k))$ where $k \ge 1$ be the
kernel of the homomorphism $Aut(F_n) \to Aut(F_n/\gamma_{k+1}(F))$
determined by the natural homomorphism $F_n \to F_n/\gamma_{k+1}(F).$

($(\mathcal A_n(k) : k \ge 1)$ is called the Johnson filtration of $Aut(F_n);$

$\gamma_k(G)$ denotes the $k$-th terms of the lower central series of a group $G,$
$\gamma_1(G)$ being equal to $G$).

I do not know an example of a group homomorphism
$f : Aut(F_n) \to G$ which
takes ***all*** terms of the Johnson filtration
$(\mathcal A_n(k))$ to the same ***nontrivial***
subgroup:
$$
1 \ne f(\mathcal A_n(1))=f(\mathcal A_n(2)) = \ldots = f(\mathcal A_n(k)) = \ldots
$$
I would be very grateful for such an example, or for an argument
that homomorphisms like that do not exist.

Comment: Gilman proved that $\mathrm{Aut}(F_n)$ is residually finite alternating.  So there is an example unless $\mathrm{Aut}(F_n/\gamma_k(F_n))$ map onto arbitrarily large alternating groups as $k\to\infty$.  I've no idea whether the latter is true or not.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. What is required of Aut(Fnk(Fn)) to guarantee existence of an example in question seems to be probable. 

Comment: The paper in question is: Gilman, Robert, Finite quotients of the automorphism group of a free group, *Canad. J. Math.* 29 (1977), no. 3, 541--551. 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer seems to be affirmative. We use the idea of Henry Wilton that the image might be taken as an alternating group $A_q$, a *simple* one (see his comment above). Let $K=\mathcal A(1).$ Then

$\mathcal A(m) \ge [K,K,\ldots,K]=[..[K,K],..,K]\qquad (m\quad times) \qquad (*)$

Take a nontrivial $\alpha \in [K,K]$ and a surjective homomorphism $\Delta: \mathrm{Aut}(F_n) \to A_q$ which doesn't vanish at $\alpha$.

Then 
$$  
A_q =\mathrm{NormalClosure}(\Delta(\alpha))=\Delta([K,K])=\Delta(K).  
$$
It follows that 
$$  
\Delta( [K,K,\ldots,K])=A_q  
$$ 
and by $(*)$  $\Delta( \mathcal A(m))=A_q  $ for every $m \ge 1.$

Comment: Nice argument!. 